# Yii2 - How to include view data in another view page?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am new to YII use yii2 basic. Actually I want to know how to include another view page from view of the same folder. Suppose I am in view  home.php. I need to include post.php  view page in home.php body. How will I perform this?

Comment: This question needs a lot more content if we're going to get to an answer for you. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and review your post. It'll help us understand the problem better, and get to the answer you need.

Comment: In addition, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We are here to help with specific problems in code, but not to develop and write code for you. If you have attempted something which does not work, please show us, and detail what is not working.

Comment: thanks for  advice! actually i am not know how to manage this problem so i asked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should simply use [`render()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#render()-detail) :

```
<?= $this->render('post'); ?>
```

And if you need the same parameters :

```
<?= $this->render('post', $_params_); ?>
```